# Template functor with any parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create template functor, which will take as arguments object and member function with any number of parameters. I can't figure out how to write the code correctly with templates.

```
template<typename ItemT,
     class T,
     typename ...Args>
struct Builder
{
    ItemT operator()(T& object, ItemT (T::*method)(Args...), Args && ... args)
    {
        return (object.*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct Object
{
    int method(int, int, int) { return 4; }
};


int main()
{
    Object obj;    
    Builder<int, Object>()(obj, &Object::method); // Error here
}
```

If I make Object::method with no parameters - code compiles. But with parameters - no.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'int Builder::operator ()(T &,ItemT (__thiscall Object::* )(void))': cannot convert argument 2 from 'int (__thiscall Object::* )(int,int,int)' to 'int (__thiscall Object::* )(void)'   drafts  c:\drafts\main.cpp  139

Comment: You forgot to pass to define what `typename ...Args` is when you declared the `Builder` object.

Comment: You need `Builder<int, Object, int, int, int>`, and you need to actually pass the three ints that `Object::method` wants as arguments. More generally, it's not clear what the point of the exercise is. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: What Nathan said. This is also the reason the standard library provides various "make_*" free functions that just construct objects. So deduction of the template arguments can happen. With c++1z, constructors will also be able to deduce template parameters for the class, making your code valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to change the current definition of `Builder`, this is how you need to instantiate it:

```
Builder<int, Object, int, int, int>()(obj, &Object::method, 0, 0, 0);
//      ^       ^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^
//      ItemT   |    |                                      |
//              T    Args...                                args...
```

The `args...` parameter expansion in the `operator()` call must match the `TArgs...` pack passed to `Builder` itself.

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3No4mTq0x8f8s7PR)

---

Here's an alternative *less strict* design:

```
template<typename T>
struct Builder
{
    template <typename TFnPtr, typename... Args>
    auto operator()(T& object, TFnPtr method, Args && ... args)
    {
        return (object.*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

The above `Builder` can be used like this:

```
int main()
{
    Object obj;    
    Builder<Object>()(obj, &Object::method, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

In this case the type of *member function pointer* is deduced through `TFnPtr` and not constrained to any particular set of parameters. The variadic parameters are not part of `Builder` anymore - they're part of `Builder::operator()`, so they can be deduced and forwarded to `(object.*method)`.

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IWTlIEzUYcl7CRGB)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid templating on `Builder` altogether and solely rely on template argument deduction:

```
struct Builder {
    template <typename Obj, typename R, typename ... FArgs, typename ... Args>
    R operator()(Obj& obj, R (Obj::*fn)(FArgs...), Args&&... args) {
        return (obj.*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

I chose to use two parameter packs to allow perfect forwarding: the value categories of the `operator()` call do not necessarily match the targeted method. This also allows for implicit conversion of arguments when applying the member function pointer. Note that this implementation will not match `const` methods of `Obj`.

You can of course relax it a bit using `auto` return type (C++14) or trailing return type (C++11). Since Vittorio's answer already presented you the C++14 way, I'll tackle the latter. The `operator()` then becomes:

```
template <typename Obj, typename FnPtr, typename ... Args>
auto operator()(Obj& obj, FnPtr fn, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype((obj.*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    return (obj.*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then, usage will simply be:

```
Object obj;
Builder()(obj, &Object::method, 0, 0, 0);
```

<kbd>[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60145c7b90a35eb)</kbd> on Coliru.